# Oracle WebCenter Content Remote Intradoc Client 12.2.1

Tags: java, oracle12c, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I have been looking all over the Oracle website for the library(jars) for the Oracle WebCenter Content Remote Intradoc Client (12.2.1) and all I can find is the API reference but not the jar files to download. We are upgrading an application that is currently using the 11g version of RIDC but I would prefer to use the newer version rather than the older one. I can find references to a 12.2.1 version in a lot of Oracle documentation but that is it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I maintain a Maven repo [here](https://bintray.com/jhult/maven/oracle.ucm%3Aridc). You can download the JAR file directly from there via the *Files* tab.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Quick question. Does the newer version need all of the dependent jar files, like the http jar, like the 11.1.1?

Comment: Yes, it does. My POM file has the dependencies in it.

Answer (score 0):

You find it on your WCC server, under .../oracle_common/ucm/Distribution/RIDC/